# ASP.NET MVC 5 is too slow on development

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to **ASP.NET** so I might be missing something in the picture. I'm using **Visual Studio Community Edition**, working in **Code First** mode, which I read uses **IIS Express** on my machine and **LocalDB**.

Issue is, each time I click on any link, let's say `/Student/Index`, it takes about 10 to 15 seconds to load and sometimes even more. I'm running the web app by pressing the green arrow (F5) which should attach a debugger, is that the reason it is so slow or am I missing something else?

**PS:** I'm following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial so I'm scaffolding every controller.

Comment: Is "Loading symbols for ..." quickly blinking in the VS status bar on each request?

Comment: some times, but not always

Comment: browser link is the one causing massive slow-downs for me but I disable it once I figured it out.

Comment: Might be an idea to edit your question to give us an idea of your computers specs, Visual Studio can be a bit demanding.

Comment: Specs are fine, it's a gamer pc

Comment: Generally, a PC that's used for gaming will be beefy enough, but simply the fact that it's used for gaming doesn't guarantee it's great at other things. Gaming obviously relies mostly on the GPU, which doesn't matter a bit to something like Visual Studio which will need CPU power. You could game on an i3 if you've got a beefy graphics card, but an i3 would be completely insufficient for Visual Studio. Also, Visual Studio would ironically probably use much more RAM than any game would.

Comment: can you change .Net framework version?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. That is why it's slow. There's a lot that has to happen to allow debugging and all that takes time. Plus, by starting and stopping debugging, you're also starting and stopping IIS Express each time if your project has the default of setting `Enable Edit and Continue` checked. In other words, each time you start debugging the whole IIS and ASP.NET machinery has to spin up completely fresh before all the work of attaching the debugger even begins.

First, check the properties of your project and if `Enable Edit and Continue` is checked, uncheck it. Then, when you stop debugging, you can actually continue to browse your development site without having to debug again. This is great for things like HTML/JS/CSS changes because it allows you to instantly reload the page, and as long as you remember to rebuild when you make C# code changes, you can even reload the page to see those changes without having to debug again. In this way, you will only need to actually run in debugging mode if you truly need to step into your code line by line and inspect variables. Otherwise, just run once and reload.

Also, there's an option somewhat buried, to just run the site without debugging. Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer, go to View > View in Browser. This will start up IIS Express, but not all the debugging machinery.

Comment: Project properties, under the Debuggers section, have ASP.NET and Enable Edit and Continue both enabled. Do I disable both or only the latter?